# Is String s = "foobar" atomic?

Tags: java, atomic

Is `String s = "foobar";` atomic?

Assigning a object-reference should be, but I'm no really sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many great answers have already been give here. Still I want something more "official" about claims like "All reference assignments are atomic in java", and why `String s = "foobar"` does not create a new object at runtime. Here is what is written in [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf). (Abbr. JLS).

Below are some examples:

```java
String str1 = "foo";                // line 1, atomic
String str2 = "foo" + "bar";        // line 2, atomic
String str3 = str1;                 // line 3, atomic
String str4 = str1 + str2;          // line 4, not atomic
String str5 = new String("foobar"); // line 5, not atomic
```

**Line 1 and line 2 are atomic** because:

1. They are both constant expressions, and are computed at compile time. There are no object construction occurred at runtime.

> JLS - 15.28: A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using ... literals of primitive type and literals of type String.

> JSL - 3.10.5: Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.

2. Writes to and reads of references are always atomic.

> JLS - 17.7: Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

**Line 3 is atomic** because:

There is only a reference assignment in this line.

> JLS - 17.7

**Line 4 is not atomic** because:

By concat two string variables, a new String object is created at runtime. Object construction is not atomic.

> JLS - 15.8.1 - String Concatenation Operator +: The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28).

> JLS - 3.10.5 - String literals: Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.

**Line 5 is not atomic** because:

A String object is constructed at runtime in this line.

Answer (score 21):

**Yes**. All reference assignments are atomic in java.

Just note that a composite statement like `String s = new String("foobar")` is not atomic, because it comprises of an object creation and then an assignment separately.

Also note that "assignments to long and double variables may not be atomic", from [JLS-17.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7)

Comment: It should also be noted that assignments to `long` and `double` variables are *not* atomic: see [JLS chapter 17.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7) for more information.

Comment: To emphasize your last sentence: As I understand the JLS, the following behavior is fine: 1. Allocate space for 'new String'. 2. assign uninitialized object to s. 3. run constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if you're worried about race conditions, you should at least be aware of 'synchronized' methods/blocks.

And note that this is not atomic because it contains two operations:

```
String s = string_a + string_b;
```

Comment: I only see one operation, what are the two operations?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen The operations I see are: 1. `StringBuilder` instanciation ; 2. `sb.append(string_a)` ; 3. `sb.append(string_b)` ; 4. `sb.toString()` ; 5. assign to `s`