# Java String instantiation and assignment atomicity

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

This is related to [Is String s = "foobar" atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421558/is-string-s-foobar-atomic) . Im a bit confused by the answer there... Assignments are atomic, thats fine. But if we have

```
String s = "s";
```

Wouldn't the steps to execute this line be 
1 - assign location of a new String instance to reference s (so its effectively not null, even though constructor for of a new String did not yet run) 
2 - run constructor?

So, only time this assignment should happen atomically is if "s" is interned?

Isnt this exactly how reads of partially constructed objects happens?

Not a duplicate - my question is not whether assignment is atomic. My question is what if "s" is not yet interned (effectively does not exist at time of assignment) and if its possible.

Comment: constants like `1`, `"s"` exist before all other actions of the program

Comment: How is this question not identical to the one you've linked to?

Comment: Good question.  Since strings are immutable, I can see that if the String literal "s" has already been created, this action would be atomic since it would just assign the existing item from the String pool to the new reference.  But what if string literal "s" has not yet been created?  Wouldn't the JVM need to create a String "s" and assign it to reference s?

Comment: Basically because Im not asking whether assignment is atomic, Im asking why and how String is different from any other object.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the value is assigned before the constructor is ran?

Comment: One of the reasons assignment is atomic is *because* constructors are run before assignment.  The object must exist in memory before a reference can be made to it.  This isn't unique to `String`.  Additionally, no constructors are being called in your example.  The `"s"` object already exists, as ACV mentioned.

Comment: also JLS says all assignments of references are atomic.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, you're correct, I was over thinking it at this point... However, it is very much possible for another reading thread to see a reference s to a String and not see its underlying char array, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an atomic operation.
Maybe this will help ([JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)):

> Compile-time constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

So I am not sure the String constructor is called here.